# Java: Split don't working

Tags: java, string

i'm creating a code, and in a a string:

```
   String server = "false|Nao conectado!";
   String status[] = server.split("|", 2);
   System.out.println(status[0] + " - " + status[1]); //t - rue
```

How to parse the "false" in a string, and the rest in other?

Comment: That's because the `"|"` is interpreted as a regex.

Comment: change to other?

Comment: @DaviDEV: use `"\\|"` instead.

Comment: `String status[] = server.split("\\|", 2);` should help you

Comment: Worked! Thanks soo much.